# How can I return a list after a recursion?

Tags: r, recursion

I want to do a code that do bubble sort, but the program has to return a list with the ordered vector and the number of comparasions.

I tried a lot of things, but because of recursion the list is a mess

```
ord_rc <- function(x, comp = 0){
  if(length(x)<=1)return(x[1])
  for(i in 1:(length(x)-1)){
    if(x[i]>x[i+1]){
      comp <- comp + 1
      aux <- x[i+1]
      x[i+1] <- x[i]
      x[i] <- aux
    }
  }
  w <- x[1:(length(x)-1)]
  return(list(c(ord_rc(w),x[length(x)])), comp)
}
```

Comment: Remove `comp` from the `return` statement.

Comment: I need the number of comparisons too

Comment: `return` takes exactly one argument, you are giving it two. If you want to return the number of comparisons, you need to include it with the return value as a single argument. In order to do that, you will also need to have `ord_rc` deal with a `list` input and extract the data and comparisons from its input argument.

Comment: If what you need is the number of comparisons, why a recursive bubble sort? It's much easier to program an iterative one and it will return whatever you want it to.

Comment: Yes, but this is an exercise of my statistics course.